# overriding the ctrl-p keyboard shortcut with a custom application

Tags: c#

Am trying to build a C# application that intercepts printjobs. The application is supposed to execute when the user presses the ctrl+p. Is there a way i can replace the function of this keyboard shortcut so that it may execute my own app rather than the default Windows printing application or how can i create a custom keyboard shortcut for my app?

Comment: That won't work for something like Word.

Comment: please explain further...

Comment: Word has a completely custom print pipeline; it does not use the standard print dialog.

Comment: Also, what about menus / toolbars?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [keyboard hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to be notified whenever the user presses any key, anywhere.

However, you won't be able to find out what's being printed.

Instead, you should create a virtual printer.

Comment: i am trying to build the virtual printer in c# but my employer requires me to do it in Java. Is there a way that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.p))
    {

        return true;
    }


    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

That should override CTRL+P for you

Comment: What is the base class of this class?

Comment: one more thing, how do I refer to my application?